In a self-referencing entity, how to prevent auto-population of fields which are lookups of such entity when in 'New' in child record associated view?
We have a self-referencing entity (i.e., the form for such entity has some fields which are a look-up of records in such entity).
The records in such entity are hierarchical (e.g., record A is the parent of record B.)
In the 'parent record' field on the form for Record B, we enter 'Record A'.
The form has a child record sub-grid so we can easily see all children of a given record. If I am in Record A, then click into the associated view of the child record sub-grid, then click the New record button, each field on the form for the new record is auto-populated with 'Record A'.’
How can I prevent this incorrect/annoying behaviour?
N.B. This behaviour does not happen if I click the New record button from the top of any given record (i.e., not from within the associated view), but that is essentially disabling the helpful child record sub-grid functionality.

We have written code to delete the annoying auto-populated field text, but this is essentially sweeping the problem under the carpet.

If you go to the lookup relationship under customizations, you can see field mappings in order to pre-populate these fields whenever users tried to create the associated record from a subgrid, this is nice to have so you can remove the mappings to achieve what you want.

You can refer this blog for more details.
